# How to display in Smarty3 part of template which is in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I'm dealing with a task, which is partially done by someone else. So I have some texts in database and need to take them and add to existing templates. The problem is, texts include some variables, which I want to display (they are provided to template). Now I can see only curly brackets and name of variable inside, not its value.

PHP:

```
$var = "{$rest_name} offers good {$cuisine} food.";
$smarty->assign("rest_name", "My Rest");
$smarty->assign("cuisine", "thai");
$smarty->assign("desc", $var);
```

TPL:

```
{$desc}
```

Displays `{$rest_name} offers good {$cuisine} food.` but I want to see there `My Rest offers good thai food.`.

I cannot do this in PHP as different parts of application deliver data, so only point where everything is known is a template.

How can I force Smarty to render PHP variable as a part of template?

Comment: load your small snippet as a template do the replacements then include that template in your main template I don't believe smarty supports inclusive replacements like you want to do though read its docs it may allow sub template inclusive replacements iff you pass an array in.  But the issue is your $var isn't in your primary template its just a variable (you could use php replacements rather than smarty replacements though I guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to use single quotes in PHP for `{$rest_name} offers good {$cuisine} food.`. Otherwise you get warnings that variables are not defined, so correct code in PHP is:

```
$var = '{$rest_name} offers good {$cuisine} food.';
$smarty->assign("rest_name", "My Rest");
$smarty->assign("cuisine", "thai");
$smarty->assign("desc", $var);
```

In Smarty you can use:

```
{include file="string:$desc"}
```

it will display parsed string immediately.

You can assign it to variable using:

```
{include file="string:$desc" assign="assigned"}
some other stuff here
{$assigned}
```

In both case you will get your desired output:

> My Rest offers good thai food.

Comment: Works as a hell, thank you. I found already string:xxx but didn't get it properly. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @Kania You're welcome. You can also use `string:` to parse Smarty strings in PHP